# Should this really return an empty String()?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, attributes, custom-attributes

I have an attribute class:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)> _
Public Class DirectoryAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Private _attribute As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal attribute As String)
        _attribute = attribute
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Attribute As String
        Get
            Return _attribute
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And interfaces and classes:

```
Public Interface IDirentoryEntity
    <DirectoryAttribute("Name")> _
    Property Name As String
End Interface

Public Interface IOrganizationalUnit
    Inherits IDirectoryEntity
End Interface

Public Class OrganizationalUnit
    Implements IOrganizationalUnit

    ' Implementing IOrganizationalUnit here...'
End Class

Public Interface IIdentifiableDirectoryEntity
    Inherits IDirectoryEntity

    <DirectoryAttribute("sAMAccountName")> _
    Property Login As String
End Interface

Public Interface IGroup
    Inherits IIdentifiableDirectoryEntity
End Interface

Public Class Group
    Implements IGroup

    Private _attributes() As String

    ' Implementing IGroup here...'

    Private ReadOnly Property Attributes() As String()
        Get
            If (_attributes Is Nothing) Then
                Dim attr() As DirectoryAttribute = _
                    CType(GetType(Group).GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DirectoryAttribute), True), DirectoryAttribute())

                If (attr Is Nothing OrElse attr.Length = 0 OrElse attr(0) Is Nothing) Then _
                    Return New String(0) { }

                _attributes = New String(attr.Length) { }

                For index As Integer = 0 To attr.Length - 1 Or _attributes.Length - 1 Step 1
                    _attributes(index) = attr(index).Attribute
                Next
            End If

           Return _attributes
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

With that said, shall the `Private Property Attributes() As String()` not return the values of `DirectoryAttribute` placed over the interfaces properties as well, since I specify **True** in the inheritance parameter of the `Type.GetCustomAttributes` method?

Comment: http://hyperthink.net/blog/getcustomattributes-gotcha/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two main points of confusion:

1. Your code is looking up attributes on a type, and the attributes are applied to properties. If you want to retrieve the attribute, you'll need to look them up on a property like Login or Name.
2. Regardless, there's a difference between inheritance and implementation. The class Group *implements* the interface IGroup, so you won't see any attributes defined on IGroup show up when you ask for *inherited* attributes on Group. If you want attributes on an interface that a type implements, you'll need to ask about the interface directly, you can't go through the type.